# Bash script shows the same grade

Tags: bash

I have to write a bash script that the user enter a name from a list of students and grades and then it displays the name and the grade. It is a binary search and I have to sort the list first and I have to use the middle point to check for names. I wrote this code but no matter what names I enter it just displays the same grade and if the name is not in the list it shows the name together with the fixed grade.

```
sort -o sorted.dat sort.dat
((count = 0))
while read names[$count]; do
((count++))
done<sorted.dat


# Store the names and grades into arrays
names=( $( cut -d: -f1 name.txt ) )
grades=( $( cut -d: -f2 name.txt ) )

# Prompt user for a name
echo "Type the student's name (use proper capitalization!), followed by [ENTER]:"

# Read the user's response
read names

length=${#names[@]}
start=0
end=$((length - 1))
match=0

while [[ $start -le $end ]]; do
     middle=$((start + ((end - start)/2)))
     middle_name=${names[$middle]}
     if [[  $middle_name -gt $name ]]; then
         end=$((middle-1))
         echo "${name}'s grade is a(n): ${grades[$name]}."
     elif [[ $middle_name -lt $name ]]; then
         start=$((middle+1))
         echo "${name}'s grade is a(n): ${grades[$name]}."
     else
         # A match was found
         match=1
         echo "${name}'s grade is a(n): ${grades[$middle_name]}."
         break
     fi
done

# Check if a match was found
if [[ $match = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find that student..."
fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You can use `readarray` to read a file into an array, instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: `-gt` and `-lt` are for comparing numbers, not strings.

Comment: You're overwriting the `names` array that came from the sorted file with `names=( $( cut -d: -f1 name.txt ) )`